# Plumbing vent frozen

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

So I have a frozen vent pipe.
A plumber tried to use a snake on it and said he's just getting ice chips. There is no cap on it and of course it's pointed straight up - temperatures have been down around -15 to -20 the last couple of nights.

Any ideas for how to thaw the vent pipe?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37631/is-there-a-way-to-thaw-a-frozen-pipe-if-you-cant-access-the-pipe

Comment: Was a plumber up on your roof in this weather? How far down is the blockage? This is in the attic or above the roof? How did enough water get into the vent to freeze?